# in application insights, how to find the number of servers/instances for a web service at a point in time?

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

If you look at live metrics in AI for a web service, it shows the number of servers currently active (this is dynamic, it goes up and down dependent on load).

We have some periodic major site issues, which we think could be when Azure sales up and adds a new instance, but cant find any way of recording/tracking/graphic/querying this.

The number of servers is shown in "live Metrics". Right now I can see we have 5.

They are also show in Performance->roles, but this only shows the number of servers (aka roles) right now, I cant see any history unfortunately.

any ideas how to see if/when a new instance was created and/or destroyed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's difficult to find out when a new instance was created / destroyed in history, since app service plan does not support `diagnostics settings`.

The most similar way is to query the requests logs then you may have the change to figure out. The query like below(to write the query, in azure portal -> your application insights -> Logs):

```
requests 
| project timestamp, cloud_RoleName, cloud_RoleInstance
| order by timestamp desc
```

[image]